# How do I make certain frontend pages accessible only by admin?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, frontend

How do I make certain frontend pages accessible only by admin? I have tried using Mage::getSingleton('core/session') and Mage::getSingleton('admin/session') to no good end.  Any suggestions?

Oh, and by pages I mean frontend controller actions in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest observing controller action predispatch events like this:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <yourgropupname_yourmodulename>
                <class>yourmodulename/observer</class>
                <method>myPredispatchObserver</method>
            </yourgropupname_yourmodulename>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

It will fire on every controller action call.

Then inside of `myPredispatchObserver` method you can check if current controller is one from those you want to restrict to admin user. You can get current controller name like this:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Finally you can check if current session belongs to admin. You can try any of the following methods:

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'))->isLoggedIn());

// or

Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();

// or

Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
```

Finally if user is not an admin redirect him to the referring page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but magento still splits admin and customer session. Therefore you don't know in the frontend whether some user is admin and logged in.

Magento sets two cookies, one namened `frontend` and one named `adminhtml`. If magento initializes PHP's cookie support with `session_name` `frontend`, you get the customer's data, if magento uses `adminhtml`, you load the admin data.

What you can do is write an admin controller and get the data via AJAX, but then they still are submitted from admin.